# Hyperledger v1.0 channel

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In Hyperledger 1.0 could I share ledger between channels?
For example, if I want to create 2 channels, one for reading and the other for writing (it's like access control), how could I synchronize the ledgers if every channel has its own ledger.
is there any other solution?
Thank you

Comment: Did you find this out?

Comment: no, but  i decided to make for the moment two chainecode one for reading and the other for writing and if user A can't write i will deploy for him only the chaincode of reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you want to use channels for flow control. This is not what channels are for. They are a construct modelling a sub-chain for privacy purposes. A channel exists on a specified set of peers and runs chaincode or chaincodes that are relevant to the channel's purpose (often a set of transactions between specific participants that require privacy).

Flow control, on the other hand, is required on a single channel and chaincode combination as key clashes in the same database partition are fatal to a transaction. A key clash happens when a transaction in a block is trying to commit a change to a key that a previous transaction **in the same block** has already changed. The transaction is immediately failed and that is recorded in the block.

**EDIT**: The late failure is **NOT** recorded in the block in any way that I can find, however you do get notified through the event hub of the MVCC failure. Hyperledger Composer conveniently sends you this notification in the catch block of the "transaction" SDK call.

To get around that, a chaincode should avoid using convenience keys to record status etc because every transaction then comes into conflict. In addition, adding flow control for asset keys is a great idea in that you really want to send changes to a specific asset only when there are no outstanding transactions against that asset. A queue can be used to smooth out the flow in case of a burst of activity.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i just have a last question : i saw in fabric-composer ACL how could we use something like that in fabric.

Comment: @MyHMEG The composer data modeling language does include a powerful access control language. 

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/acl_language.html

You define access to assets or parts of assets (down to a single property). You can specify roles or even specific individuals. You can also add an expression to perform more complex state checks. The rule engine will process from more specific to least specific to get the appropriate access. I consider this method a redaction filter, returning only allowable properties.